# c# WPF run-time adding row that is binded to a List<class>

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a datagrid that has lets say 2 columns for now. "App Name", and "App Location". At first there's no row just 2 columns, but when I click a button and a OpenFileDialog opens, I choose .exe file then I want that .exe filename and location(path) be in my datagrid.

At first I manage to do it but when I'm double clicking the row it gives me error says "'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.". So I searched it and found that I have to bind the row to a list. I did it and now nothings is display in rows when I add a .exe file.

my item class

```
public class ApplicationItem
   {
       //public bool isAppRun { get; set; }
       public string appName { get; set; }
       public string appLocation { get; set; }
   }
```

my first code that works in adding but got error when Double clicked a row

```
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".exe";
        fileDialog.Filter = "Exe Files (*.exe)|*.exe";
        Nullable<bool> selected = fileDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (selected == true) //selected a file
        {
            fileName = fileDialog.SafeFileName.ToString();
            filePath = fileDialog.FileName.ToString();

            applications_grd.Items.Add(new ApplicationItem()
            {
                appName = fileName.Remove(fileName.Length - 4),
                appLocation = filePath
            });
```

2nd code where I use List then got no text in rows.

```
    string fileName = "";
    string filePath = "";
    List<ApplicationItem> appItems = new List<ApplicationItem>();

            appItems.Add(new ApplicationItem()
            {
                appName = fileName.Remove(fileName.Length - 4),
                appLocation = filePath
            });

            applications_grd.Items.Add(appItems);
```

Thanks in advance. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work In `xaml` page add

`AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

in grid and  in .cs code set

```
applications_grd.ItemsSource = appItems;
```

Comment: I think I got it to work but theres a new problem.
my grid look like this

Application    | Location   | appName   | appLocation
xx.exe             D:\xxx\xx    xx.exe           D:\xxx\xx

I dont know why but my variable appName and appLocation is in my datagrid.

Comment: Can you explain the priblem?

Comment: This is because you bind the list with grid can you tell the expected result in grid

Comment: <DataGridTextColumn Header="Application" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=appName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=appLocation}"/>

I should have only 2 column(App Name and App Location) but the variable I used to store the values is also in the grid.

Comment: set AutoGenerateColumns="False" because you are defining the columns